# Packaging a magento module - how to get extension key options

Tags: magento

When packaging a magento extension, how do you package in such a way where you get the extension key options in magento connect. i.e. the version 1.0 and 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Supported Releases" field is not a dropdown its a multi select.  You need to select both options otherwise only one will be available.

Theres a good tutorial here: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-create-extension-package-images/ - which walks you through the process.

Comment: According to [Rhonda's guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension_in_1.5#broader_extension_support) you only need to select one option. _"When uploading the 1.0 version – Magento Connect will make the 2.0 version for you."_